# Форма обратной связи не закрывается после отправки

Tags: wordpress

Сайт клонирован с WP [https://мебелъблок.рф/](https://xn--90aakb0aebcy1j.xn--p1ai/)
Много чего правил, сайт превратился после клонирования в обычный HTML сайт
Всё работает прекрасно, настроил форму обратной связи, она письма шлёт и закрываться никак не хочет!
Перепробовал много вариантов, вот ниже кусок скрипта js может кто подскажет какую-нибудь хитрую каманду?

```css
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() { // Событие отправки с формы
 . . . . . . . // Путь к PHP обработчику sendform.php
            data: form_data,
            success: function() {
$('#envelope').fadeOut(300);
/// это всё попытки закрыть форму
$(document).on('af_complete', function(event,res) {
    if(res.success) $('.pum-close popmake-close').click();
});

$('.pum-close popmake-close').addClass('active');

$(document).on('af_complete', function(event,res) {
    if(res.success) $('.close').click();
});
$(document).on('af_complete', function(event, response) {
    if (response.success) {
       UIkit.modal('pum-close popmake-close ').hide();
    } });       }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="popmake-143" class="pum-container popmake theme-130 pum-responsive pum-responsive-small responsive size-small">

                

                            <div id="pum_popup_title_143" class="pum-title popmake-title">
                Вызвать замерщика           </div>
        

        

                <div class="pum-content popmake-content">
            <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f142-o4" lang="ru-RU" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/#wpcf7-f142-o4" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate" id="form142">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="142">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.0">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="ru_RU">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f142-o4">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0">
</div>
<p>&nbsp;<br>
<label> Ваше имя (*)<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </label><br>
<br>
<label> Ваш телефон (*)<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-phone"><input type="tel" name="your-phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit button">

</p>
<input type="hidden" name="your-email" value="alex_yz@bk.ru" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="your-subject" value="Вызвать замерщика" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="your-message" value="Вызвать замерщика" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="your-call-gage" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden your-call-gage">
<p><script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { var output = $('#wpcf7-f142-o2 form .wpcf7-response-output'); output.detach(); output.prependTo('#wpcf7-f142-o2 form'); });</script></p>
<input type='hidden' class='wpcf7-pum' value='{"closepopup":true,"closedelay":0,"openpopup":true,"openpopup_id":0}'><div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>
        </div>


                

                            <button type="button" class="pum-close popmake-close" aria-label="Закрыть">
            X            </button>
    
    
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, вашим *«Сайт с WP https://мебелъблок.рф/ сайт Всё работает прекрасно, Всем Спасибо!»* не заменяйте ваш оригинальный вопрос. Я вернул его к оригинальному тексту. Вашу благодарность вы можете выразить в комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Есил вы используете Сontact Form 7 (а судя по разметке это так), то у него в js events. https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
  alert( "Fire!" );
  // Your code for closing popup.
}, false );
```

Comment: Там вообще не про ВП :) : "сайт превратился после клонирования в обычный HTML сайт "